Why is opencv blob detector recognising some blobs but not other (identical?) ones?
I'm using SimpleBlobDetector and it's generally working. However sometimes it is not detecting blobs and I have no idea why. For example, in the attached image it has correctly identified three circles, but refuses to recognise the fourth (top right) , which to me looks identical (in case you can't see in the image, it does have a contiguous perimeter). I've turned off all the parameters (except area) to see if any of those was causing the misidentification, but still no luck. Any thoughts?

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params() 

# Set Area filtering parameters 
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = np.ceil(bwImage.shape[0]/blobParams[0])

# Set Circularity filtering parameters 
params.filterByCircularity = False 
params.minCircularity = blobParams[1]

# Set Convexity filtering parameters 
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = blobParams[2]

# Set inertia filtering parameters 
params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = blobParams[3]

# Create a detector with the parameters 
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params) 

Thanks to Cincinnatus' reply, I tried the closing operation (with a trial and error 3x3 kernel), and it worked - but I don't know why! You can see in the image below the closing op seems to have eroded a lot of the circles, and yet now the detector is recognising all four....!??


Use morphology operators to preprocess the image. Use an opening operation to remove the small particles and a closing operation to remove the holes inside the circles. Then apply the blob detector to the preprocessed image. Take a look at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

morphological operation like erosion and dilation do not perform correctly especially when you have noisy images. sometimes Hough transform is proper solution and sometimes you should looking for advanced methods and algorithms.

hough on noisy images just as much of a gamble. it's usually a good idea to deal with noise first. -- we need to see the source data. the picture you showed us is already thresholded. we can't fix that.

You tried a closing operator? It looks more like you used an opening operator to remove the noise but you haven;t used a closing operator to fill the holes as suggested.

That was my first thought, but this is the code I used:
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
bwImage = cv2.morphologyEx(bwImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
Could the issue be I'm doing it on a black on white image? Do I need to invert the image first?
Edit: Yes, I think that was the problem. Running the closing op on a white on black image seems to work!

many algorithms assume that object/foreground is white and background is black. if your picture does not conform to that, invert it.
